# What is the meaning of "Julia Child wasn't always Julia Child"?

Tags: meaning

Julia Child and Mario Batali are famous for cooking.

> Eric: So write a blog about cooking.
>
> Julie: "I'm not a real cook, like Julia Child or Mario Batali.
>
> Eric: **Julia Child wasn't always Julia Child**.

Is Eric saying Julia Child famous only for few days?

Comment: Please give a source for this text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is telling Julie that before "Julia Child" learned to cook, she was like Julie (couldn't cook formally). It is just a starting point.

This means that Julia Child wasn't born a famous chef. She was like anyone else (and Julie in your example), then learned to cook formally and became a famous chef.

Comment: I already mentioned Julia Child is famous at **cooking**.

Comment: I'm saying that Julia Child wasn't born a famous chef. She was like anyone else (and Julie in your example), then learned to cook formally and became a famous chef.

Comment: @Stephie Fair enough. I added it to my answer.